# connection refuse for a LM related application

Tags: centos, process

There is a `lmadmin` file regarding the flexlm tool. Problem is that when I run the binary, it doesn't print any output and when I grep for the process, there is no such process.

I decided to run it with `strace`. Fortunately, it shows a `connection refused` error. However, I can not figure out what is the problem exactly and how should I resolve it.

The last lines are

```
read(3, "# Added by rocks report host #\n#"..., 4096) = 357
access("/etc/sysconfig/32bit_ssse3_memcpy_via_32bit_ssse3_memmove", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x5555f000, 4096)                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8090),  sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
close(3)                                = 0
chdir("/share/apps/Viz/8.1/FNPLicenseServerManager") = 0
clone(child_stack=0,  flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0) = 12984
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

The full output is available at  [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/j9yWz4dU)

UPDATE:

It has been mentioned that maybe the port is not open. Since I am using Rocks, I followed the [document](http://central6.rocksclusters.org/roll-documentation/base/6.1.1/firewall.html) to open the port.

```
# rocks report host firewall cluster | grep 8090
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 8090 -j ACCEPT
# rocks sync host firewall cluster
#
```

Still by running `strace ./lmadmin` I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

You've found the line of interest:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8090),  sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

This is telling you that a connection to the local machine on port 8090 is being refused. The reason it's being refused is most likely that there's nothing listening on this port for connections. There are other possible explanations, but they are less likely.

Extrapolating from your question, I'm guessing that either you're not passing the correct name of the FlexLM licensing server to the command you're running, or you've mis-configured the local machine to point to itself instead of the external FlexLM licensing server. If the licensing server is supposed to be running locally, then it's simply not been started, or it has crashed for some reason.

Comment: Please see the updated post

Comment: What does `netstat -tuln | grep 8090` say? I didn't say the port isn't open - although that was a possibility - I said there's likely nothing listening on that port.

Comment: see `# iptables -L | grep 8090` which says `ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8090` and `netstat -tuln | grep 8090` which is empty!

Comment: That means there is nothing listening on the port. The output of your `iptables` command is irrelevant - you've either got a client misconfiguration or a non-running server.